# How to make relation between user term and nodes terms?

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms

I'm newbie to Drupal. I'm in a process to restrict the user based on the node taxonomy term, and the user taxonomy term. For the user's I have attached a custom field of type **Term Reference**. I have a Taxonomy Vocabulary called **Company**. Inside that vocabulary I have created two terms **Tata**, **Infos**.
There are totally 100 nodes, out of these 60 were belongs to **Tata** and the 40 belongs **Infos**.

Now these terms would be reflect to the user profile page as radio button. When admin select **Tata** for particular user, then that user might be able to see only the **Tata** tagged nodes and vice versa. I have tried [tac_lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite) and [content_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module before adding custom fields to user profile page, but not my requirement is getting finished. Is there any way to achieve this!!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using view :

1. add field in views
2. add relationship of user
3. add expose filter against term id or term name
4. if you want show on user profile page add contextual filter against user id

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can tell more detail about this process. Since I'm new to drupal.

Comment: check these links https://www.acquia.com/blog/totally-beginner-tutorial-views-drupal-7, https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/views/tutorial